# How do I insert this url in a footnote

Tags: hyperref, urls, href

https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/legado?url=https:%2F%2Fwww4.bcb.gov.br%2Fglossario.asp%3FDefinicao%3D1676%26idioma%3DP%26idpai%3DGLOSSARIO

I've tried href, hyperref, URL, or none at all, just \footnote{https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/legado?url=https:%2F%2Fwww4.bcb.gov.br%2Fglossario.asp%3FDefinicao%3D1676%26idioma%3DP%26idpai%3DGLOSSARIO}

or \footnote[1]{https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/legado?url=https:%2F%2Fwww4.bcb.gov.br%2Fglossario.asp%3FDefinicao%3D1676%26idioma%3DP%26idpai%3DGLOSSARIO}

Can't put the entire link without being clickable because latex things the "%" it's part of the code.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried with `\url`? Since, `\footnote{\url{<URL>}}` works out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Werner Unless there is % sign in the address! That's when you need the `\urldef` command.

Comment: @hair-splitter: Have you tried it? This works without problem: [Code](https://pastebin.com/raw/w115GnZ7); [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzeHc.png)

Comment: @Werner It works because `\%` was written in the URL address instead of `%`! Without changing the address, it returns with an error! In addition, using `url` package instead of `hyperref` gives a bad result! Please read the `url` user guide!

Comment: Hey guys, thank you very much. The asnwear by @hair-splitter below worked just fine, but it's good to know that I can just use "\%" to bypass the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will return error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,xurl}
\begin{document}
text\footnote{\url{https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/legado?url=https:%2F%2Fwww4.bcb.gov.br%2Fglossario.asp%3FDefinicao%3D1676%26idioma%3DP%26idpai%3DGLOSSARIO}}
\end{document}
```

In such a case, you can use the `\urldef` command. See the page 2 in [url.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf):

> Take for example the email address “myself%node@gateway.net" which
> could not be given (using “\url” or “\verb”) in a caption or parbox
> due to the percent sign. This address can be predefined with
> \urldef{\myself}\url{myself%node@gateway.net} and then you may use
> “\myself” instead of “\url{myself%node@gateway.net}” in an argument,
> and even in a moving argument like a caption because a defined-url is
> robust.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,xurl}
\begin{document}
\urldef{\myurl}\url{https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/legado?url=https:%2F%2Fwww4.bcb.gov.br%2Fglossario.asp%3FDefinicao%3D1676%26idioma%3DP%26idpai%3DGLOSSARIO}
text\footnote{\myurl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked so damn fine. Thank you very much! The problem really was the "%" in the middle of the link.

Comment: @Alexander I am glad! Please accept my answer then.

Comment: oh, sorry. didnt know about that. I'd upvoted if I could :D

Answer (score 3):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\url{https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/legado?url=https:\%2F\%2Fwww4.bcb.gov.br\%2Fglossario.asp\%3FDefinicao\%3D1676\%26idioma\%3DP\%26idpai\%3DGLOSSARIO}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't consider this to be an optimal answer, because you have to manipulate the URL, you have to type `\%` instead of the `%` sign. The `\urldef` command of the `url` package must be used for this!

Comment: Hi, @Clara. Thank you very much for the answear!